# How to prototype 9-VFQFN?

Tags: integrated-circuit, prototyping

I am working on a project that will boost my Lipo voltage to 5V.  I am looking at trying to use a boost converter like the [TPS61235P](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS61235P) from TI.  Is there a good way to prototype this IC package (9-VFQFN) without having to create a custom breakout board just for this IC?

Comment: Getting a PCB made is so cheap and convenient nowadays I gave up prototyping. I just design a circuit with a chip in it and get it made. If it doesn't work I fix it and get a new version made. Chips are so small now it's just easier that way.

Comment: Especially parts like that where you have to pay close attention to PCB layout.

Comment: Alternatively, ready made breakouts of lipo boost converters to 5V are cheap and available.

Comment: @WesleyLee the reason I was trying to create one myself was because a lot of the 5V Lipo/Li-ion boost converters that I found would limit current at around 1A when they could give potentially 2-2.5A including efficiency.

Comment: As I understand, you plan to use a Samsung phone battery for the project, right? https://www.anker.com/products/70SMNOTE3-S1W32NA Did you try to squeeze 4 Amps out of it without causing damage or protection trip? What is the discharge ratings for this battery?

Comment: @Ali Chen No, I will be using most likely Adafruit's 2500mAh Lipo battery, and will be drawing (hopefully) close to 1C.

Comment: For 3A output at 5V you CAN'T HOPE for 2.5A draw. You will need about 4.5A input to get 3A on 5V side. It was explained to you several times.

Comment: @Ali Chen I don't think I said I wanted 3A output after it was explained.  I want to have 5V at a non-limited current (whatever the current draw would allow for).

Comment: Did you check the specs for your battery? It says "discharge rate 0.5C". So you can get 900mA maximum at 5V end without abusing your battery. > 1.25A * 3.8V/5V * 0.9 = 855mA, generously assuming 90% efficiency.

Comment: @Ali Chen the datasheet says that the charge current must be "less than or equal to 2C.".  So if I order one and discharge it at 1C fully a few times without it getting too hot, then let's assume I can.  My question is asking how to prototype with a certain IC package and a 5V boost without limiting current, not over-discharging my battery.

Comment: I am just trying to help. Regarding "prototyping", you can't, without making a PCB, and only if you stop "assuming" and follow datasheets and specifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TI is usually good about listing evaluation modules on the "Tools & software" section of the product page. In this case it has a link to [TPS61236EVM-676](http://www.ti.com/tool/tps61236evm-676), available for $49 from TI direct.

Other companies may do something similar; as always examine the appropriate product page.